# How to automatically add email comments to existing JIRA issue

Tags: outlook, jira

I've done this before but can't remember how to do this anymore.

Let's say I have a JIRA issue# 967 open.
I'm emailing a couple of people with comments on this issue using my Outlook email.
What do I need to do so that this comment automatically gets added as part of the JIRA issue?

Answer (score 1):

See the [Atlassian documentation here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email#CreatingIssuesandCommentsfromEmail-Issuecommentcreation).  Replace JIRA in the URL with the version number you're on if you are using an older version, e.g. JIRA044

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you're following the guides that fits your Jira version, there is a page for each version. [Follow this guide to set up issue and comments creation via email](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email).

Basically you need to :

1. [Configure mail server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Using+Gmail+as+a+JIRA+Mail+Server) - use your exchange server or [external service as Google](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Using+Gmail+as+a+JIRA+Mail+Server).
2. [Configure a mail handler](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email#CreatingIssuesandCommentsfromEmail-SteptwoConfigureamailhandler) - probably you will want to use one of [Jira's built-in mail handlers](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email#CreatingIssuesandCommentsfromEmail-Mailhandlers).

Important notes-

- To create a comment for isser key `TEST-123` the email's subject has to contain the issue key, e.g. `Subject: Re: TEST-123 updates`.
- Emails without subject line won't be processed.
- [read this for more tips](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email#CreatingIssuesandCommentsfromEmail-handytips).